# Problem sending an email via mutt

Tags: email, mutt

I'm trying to send an email using mutt like this:

```
echo 1.txt | mutt my_email@gmail.com -s Hello -a file.tar.bz2
```

It's getting no error, but I didn't receive the email.
What's the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that you are using a local smtp server, have you checked the maillog? If that is the case, please post some of the log...

Comment: I'll be thankful if you tell me where can I find the log.

Comment: There are 2 logs that could be relevant: /var/log/mail.log and /var/log/mail.err It sounds thought that you don't have a mail server setup on your machine, did you configure mutt for a Gmail account?

Comment: If you haven't set Mutt up for Gmail use, here's a great guide on the setup required: http://lifehacker.com/5574557/how-to-use-the-fast-and-powerful-mutt-email-client-with-gmail

Answer (score 3):

Try launching mutt with debug level 1 with the command: `mutt -d 1`

I solved my problem this way (the certificate couldn't be saved, and mutt was silently not sending emails).

Comment: Why does it actually put the message into **/var/mail/** instead of sending it to the destination?

Comment: Yes, `mutt -d 1` is really useful, especially after setup `.muttrc` file (refer to https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/451259/muttrc-file-for-gmail-and-yandex, the password should be application access password) and gmail application-specific password (refer to https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/226936/how-to-install-setup-mutt-with-gmail-on-centos-and-ubuntu), then run only with `mutt -d 1` able to observe if the certificate downloading good or not, it will ask you to confirm save if success, after certificate saved you will see pulling emails from gmail happen